# Nested loop with using reversed range variable

Tags: python, range

```
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    for j in reversed(range(10)):
        print(i, j)
```

I want to change this python code using variable.

```
r = reversed(range(10))
for i in r:
    for j in r:
        print(i, j)

r1 = reversed(range(10))
r2 = reversed(range(10))      
for i in r1:
    for j in r2:
        print(i, j)
```

However, both of above for loops fix `i` with 9.

Why do this problem occurred and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reversed` produces an *iterator*, and can only be iterated over once before it is exhausted. Your inner loop tries to iterate over `r2` more than once however, so even though `i` goes through 9 down to 0, the inner loop can only produce actual numbers once.

*Recreate* the iterator inside `j` your loop:

```
r1 = reversed(range(10))
for i in r1:
    r2 = reversed(range(10))      
    for j in r2:
        print(i, j)
```

or create a list copy first, which can be iterated over more than once:

```
r1 = reversed(range(10))
r2 = reversed(range(10))
r2_copy = list(r2)
for i in r1:
    for j in r2_copy:
        print(i, j)
```

A better alternative is to use the [`itertools.product()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

r1 = reversed(range(10))
r2 = reversed(range(10))
for i, j in product(r1, r2):
    print(i, j)
```

`product()` creates an internal copy as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some other way to reverse list (as `reversed` returns generator - so you can iterate over it just once):

`r = range(10)[::-1]`

`for i in r:
     for j in r:
         print(i, j)`

`range(10)` returns a list, so you could revese it using `slice` `[::-1]`